# Django -- Models don't exist, but Django still loads them

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

Im getting a `ProgrammingError` when I try to delete a User object, this is wherever User.delete occurs, it even happens in the admin.

**The Error**

Django apparently 'thinks' that there's a relationship between `auth_user` and `apiHandlers_cardholders` which doesn't exist anywhere, the database doesn't have a column for this, and there is no `models.[y` nor `admin.py` in the app named `apiHandlers` , but Django expects it to, there is even a section of the Admin site devoted to it. This only started happening when I migrated from SQLite to PostGreSQL.

At the moment all the local dependencies (models, admin, forms and fields) are in an app called helpers, I'm not sure if this is efficient, but it keeps everything in one place and avoids complications.

**UPDATE 0.1**

No. One of the probably gonna be many updates

I used to have a problem when migrating, related to Django Rest Framework, but I eventually  managed to fix it by a quick `pip install` to a new update of restframework, it's no longer giving me any error while making migrations and migrating.

Below is the current traceback I'm getting from the Django admin, it's basically the same in the other deletion methods.

`

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/admin/auth/user/3/delete/

Django Version: 1.9.2
Python Version: 2.7.10
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'rest_framework',
 'corsheaders',
 'oauth2_provider',
 'apiHandlers',
 'frontEnd',
 'helpers',
 'nonUser']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
 'oauth2_provider.middleware.OAuth2TokenMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/Users/Mason/Documents/dev/FlowFrameWork/flow-framework/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/Mason/Documents/dev/FlowFrameWork/flow-framework/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/Mason/Documents/dev/FlowFrameWork/flow-framework/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
  541.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/Mason/Documents/dev/FlowFrameWork/flow-framework/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  149.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/Mason/Documents/dev/FlowFrameWork/flow-framework/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  57.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/Mason/Documents/dev/FlowFrameWork/flow-framework/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  244.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/Mason/Documents/dev/FlowFrameWork/flow-framework/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  67.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/Mason/Documents/dev/FlowFrameWork/flow-framework/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  149.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/Mason/Documents/dev/FlowFrameWork/flow-framework/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  63.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

File "/Users/Mason/Documents/dev/FlowFrameWork/flow-framework/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in inner
  184.                     return func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/Mason/Documents/dev/FlowFrameWork/flow-framework/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in delete_view
  1629.             [obj], opts, request.user, self.admin_site, using)

File "/Users/Mason/Documents/dev/FlowFrameWork/flow-framework/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/utils.py" in get_deleted_objects
  128.     collector.collect(objs)

File "/Users/Mason/Documents/dev/FlowFrameWork/flow-framework/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/utils.py" in collect
  193.             return super(NestedObjects, self).collect(objs, source_attr=source_attr, **kwargs)

File "/Users/Mason/Documents/dev/FlowFrameWork/flow-framework/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/deletion.py" in collect
  230.                     elif sub_objs:

File "/Users/Mason/Documents/dev/FlowFrameWork/flow-framework/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __nonzero__
  266.         return type(self).__bool__(self)

File "/Users/Mason/Documents/dev/FlowFrameWork/flow-framework/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __bool__
  262.         self._fetch_all()

File "/Users/Mason/Documents/dev/FlowFrameWork/flow-framework/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _fetch_all
  1074.             self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())

File "/Users/Mason/Documents/dev/FlowFrameWork/flow-framework/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __iter__
  52.         results = compiler.execute_sql()

File "/Users/Mason/Documents/dev/FlowFrameWork/flow-framework/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  848.             cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/Users/Mason/Documents/dev/FlowFrameWork/flow-framework/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  79.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)

File "/Users/Mason/Documents/dev/FlowFrameWork/flow-framework/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/Users/Mason/Documents/dev/FlowFrameWork/flow-framework/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
  95.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)

File "/Users/Mason/Documents/dev/FlowFrameWork/flow-framework/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

Exception Type: ProgrammingError at /admin/auth/user/3/delete/
Exception Value: relation "apiHandlers_cardholder" does not exist
LINE 1: ...user"."is_active", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "apiHandle...
                                                         ^
```

`

**UPDATE 0.2**

- I am using `./manage.py runserver` (Mac) to run it, so far I haven't managed to test it with Nginx and WSGI on my server.
- I am not getting a warning saying that it could affect another model, in the admin, for example, I am just getting this error immediately.

Comment: Can you produce a full error stack, because `ProgrammingError` is too vague for us to interpret?
Also, do you have any errors when doing `python manage.py migrate`?
Code from your app may probably be needed as well, but not sure yet which files.

Comment: @raphv Yep, just done that for you, I'm not sure which code is needed either, so only time will tell.

Comment: Did you get a message before deleting saying that changes would cascade to other models? Do you have a way of knowing what the full SQL request was (maybe with django-debug-toolbar)? Also, are you in a production-type environment (e.g. apache/nginx + wsgi) or using runserver? If you're in the first case, your app is kept in memory by the wsgi module and may refer to outdated models until you restart the server.

Comment: @raphv Done that too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very likely to be because you have a stray models.pyc file somewhere. Clear out all the *.pyc files. You can try something like this if you are on linux:

```
find . -name '*pyc' -exec 'rm' '{}' ';'
```

Follow that by `./manage.py makemigrations apihandlers` and then `./manage.py migrate`

Comment: Do you mean Every .pyc file, not just the models.pyc

Comment: clear out every pyc file while you are at it. You can use find if you are on linux

Comment: Thanks you are a life saver

Comment: Glad to have helped