# python manage.py migrate relation "" does not exist

Tags: python, django, postgresql, migration, database-migration

I have 2 models - Facility and Slot.

```
class Facility(BaseModel):

    name = models.CharField()...

class Slot(BaseModel):

    name = models.CharField()...
    slot = models.ForeignKey(Facility)
```

These work perfectly fine.

Now I am adding another model:-

```
class BlockedSlot(BaseModel):

    slots = models.ManyToManyField(Slot)
```

Now when I run python manage.py makemigrations, it successfully creates a migration file.
But when I run python manage.py migrate, it gives the error - relation "facilities_slot" does not exist.
(models are in facilities.py)

I even tried resetting the db and trying, but it still fails.

I even deleted all the existing migrations and reran makemigrations that generated the 0001_initial.py and again ran migrate, but still fails.

Comment: Try this one remove your new changes then create 0001_initial.py  then add new changes and run makemigrations and migrate

Comment: It would be easier for someone to help you if you posted the full models. In the meantime please try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38411177/267540

Comment: Are your models imported from `facilities.py` to `models.py`? What is the content of `BaseModel`?